# Sumup values of measured column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

i have 3 tables:
Datatable 1 is a usual date table with columns date and monthid(e.g. 202308 for current month), month short name (Jun-2023), quarter, year....
Datatable 2 is a event table which tracks the count of events per day.
Datatable 3 contains the sales data of different division per month (mapped on 1st of month).

I wanna show in power bi a table that shows the last 15 month with month, number of events, amount of sales, sales per event.
[table with measured values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZV7y.png)

All columns are measured.

```
_Sales = if(CALCULATE(sum(SalesDivision[Sales]))>0,CALCULATE(sum(SalesDivision[Sales])),BLANK())

_Events = COUNT(Event[Name])

_SalesPerEvent = DIVIDE([_Sales], [_Events],blank())
```

That is working pretty fine.

But now I have to sum up the sales per month for a calculated period. Which works as well.

[Table with calculated start/end as monthID (yyyymm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPBl2.png)

I tried several calculation to sum up the values, but there is something wrong.

```
_SumUp = 
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            FILTER (
                ALL ( DateTable[MonthID] ),
                DateTable[MonthID] >= DateTable[_Start]
                    && DateTable[MonthID] < DateTable[_End]
            ),
            "SpE", [_SalesPerEvent]
        ),
        [SpE]
    )
```

BTW. the datatables contains all data. The result table uses a slicer to show only the last 15 calendar month.

Where is my fault?